# Windows 7 hangs after going into sleep a second time

Tags: windows-7, bios, freeze, sleep, power-management

I've searched everywhere around Google and can't figure out why this is happening so I decide to ask here to see if anyone has a problem like this.

Like it says in the title, whenever I sleep ONCE I'm able to wake the system, but going back to sleep again AFTER waking up for the first time results in it hanging on no input and no output, with the fan spinning as fast as possible and alot of heat being spewed out by the fan as well.

I've tried various things like setting all USB Hub Root's to not get switched off for power saving, disabling USB selective suspend, disabling PCI-e link state power management, and even unplugging ALL USB devices and it wont wake up after the second attempt. And I've even waited up to a full hour of the CPU fan spinning loudly and it's still stuck trying to wake up.

The only USB devices I use are a Microsoft USB Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 (IntelliType Pro)
and a generic HID compliant mouse from Creative model number OMC90S "CREATIVE MOUSE OPTICAL LITE".
My other devices like external drives and controllers are unplugged when I'm not using them as having too many USB devices plugged in at a time causes a deadlock on almost all of the ports I have.

Here's my system specifications (Most of these are from CPU-Z):

Brand: Gateway DX4300-19
Mainboard: Gateway RS780
Chipset: AMD 780G Rev 00
Southbridge: AMD SB700 Rev 00
LPCIO: ITE IT8718
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. ver P01-A4 09/15/2009
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 810 at 2.60 GHz
RAM: 8.0 GB DDR2 Dual Channel Ganged Mode at 400 MHz
GPU: ATI Radeon HD3200 Graphics Intergrated - RS780
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium x64 OEM (Acer Group)
HDD: WDC WD10EADS-22M2B0 1.0 TB (Western Digital Green Caviar)

My BIOS has absolutely no control over how I setup the sleep mode to be either S1 or S3. So I can't check these settings or even change them.

Hybrid sleep is also disabled, I can successfully go into hibernation and wake from hibernation but this is painfully slow due to a harddrive problem I'm having with this "Green Drive". (Hibernation takes over ~3 minutes to complete)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Has this ever worked?   Have you tried reproducing after disabling all non-MS services and startups?  Have you tried a 3rd party OS (like A Linux LiveCD)?  Are all your device drivers up-to-date?  How about your BIOS?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's a BIOS problem because when I try to sleep twice in Ubuntu it freezes but produces a even worse heat buildup effect than Windows. My video drivers are up to date, just about everything in windows update that's critical was up to date. System file protection came clean too, disabling all non-MS services and startups produced the same freezing result when I come out of sleep a second time.